# How to connect to other Ubuntu machine as X Server?

Tags: xserver, putty

When I want to work on my local Linux machines from windows, I use Putty+Xming and I set the Xming port in Putty connection settings. 
This way I have a terminal on the machine and if, for example, I run the command 'firefox'  a firefox window is opened in Windows (while it is really running on the Linux machine).

I want to do the same thing from other Linux machine (they are both Ubuntu machine) connect by SSH and become this connection X Server so any graphic component will be opened on local machine. 
How can I do that?

Comment: im not sure if this you are looking for. Im using this command to run teamviewer on my other machine using ssh

 ssh -X -C -c blowfish user@192.168.0.1 -p 22 "teamviewer"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either simply open a Terminal window on your local machine and use the command

```
ssh -X user@remote
```

The $DISPLAY variable is automatically set to route via the SSH connection (i.e. it will be something like `localhost:10.0`).

Alternatively you can install the Linux version of Putty on Ubuntu and enable X11 forwarding under Connection->SSH->X11 exactly as you do for Windows (which also sets the $DISPLAY variable as above).

Comment: Thanks. I installed open ssh on the server and successfully connected  by using `ssh -X`. but why it is so slow? for example, I opened `nautilus` and it can take one minute until it opens. generally speaking I thought that the experience would be better (something like RDP in windows).